# WKWebView cannot drag Element

Tags: swift, macos, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have a macOS App that uses a WKWebView. I clone that WebView programmatically for another view. But when I try to set the new constraints to equal the main WebView like this

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: copiedWebView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.webView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: copiedWebView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.webView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: copiedWebView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.webView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: copiedWebView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.webView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

Both WebViews are not able to drag and drop something.

**Update**

Strange...when I set the height constraint `...active = false` drag and drop is working. It also does not matter if the constraint is related to the original webView or the main view.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I figured out what the problem was: The WebView – even if `isHidden = true` was "technically layered over the original WebView" – so when switching the active WebView I needed to bring the view to front.

It had nothing to do with the constraints itself.